# Easiest way to deploy my website using Visual Studio 2012 and IIS 6/7

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, webdeploy, msbuild-4.0

What's the easiest way to deploy my website as part of my build definition? I'm using Visual Studio 2012, TFS 2013. I have PowerShell at my disposal and open to making this an easy process.

It would be nice if I can pick any target machine and my build will deploy to it in a fully automated fashion.

Comment: Are you deploying to Azure, IIS, or something else?

Comment: IIS7 in a VMware environment

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple environments in sequence, like Dev->QA->Prod, then you might benefit from a release management tool that orchestrates the deployment pipeline.

TFS has a component called Release Management for Visual Studio that lets you build a pipeline and workflow with approvals that automate this process. It will manage the variables that are different between environments.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your build process you can supply arguments to MSBuild to kick off a deploy process.  The relevant arguments for you will be `DeployOnBuild`, `PublishProfile`, `DeployTarget`, and `TargetEnvPropsFile`.

Essential reading:

1. [Understanding the Build Process](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-build-process)
2. [Creating a Build Definition That Supports Deployment](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/creating-a-build-definition-that-supports-deployment)